# Constant and persistent aspect ratio correction when VIEWING photos

Tags: aspect-ratio

Here's my problem. I've a got a monitor and graphic card combination that yields slightly distorted aspect ratio. In effect, every photograph is a little too wide (should be ca 88--95% narrower). Thus, what I need is a viewer that will allow me to compensate the distortion, just as it is with movie playing using VLC etc., where you can define a correction ratio. Now photo viewing/showing is no fun - either I see a too wide image - which is unacceptable, or I have to laboriously modify it on every image being just viewed - anyway THE ONLY viewer that allows it (that I've been able to find) is FASTSTONE but even this does not make it possible to define a PERSISTENT correction ratio. Please understand me well - I have many monitors and all but this one yield correct image; so I don't want to  modify the photographs themselves as I'd have to keep two versions of each. On the other hand, the monitor in question is in fact a very big screen and nice quality TV that is otherwise perfect for such presentations. And believe me, I'm a computer specialist and I know that for this particular card-monitor set there's no better driver than the currently used, and the present settings are the best possible ones (spent several weeks on this). Well, I can't believe there's no such viewer on Earth that would have such a simple feature; however, I haven't been able to find it.
So, what I need is a viewer with a constant and persistent aspect ratio correction feature, 
Thanks for any help,
Regards, 
Tomasz

Comment: To have any descriptive meaning at all, you should mention what is the aspect ratio of the monitor, and what is the aspect ratio of the problem photos?  Short of those facts, what is the size in pixels of the screen, and the size in pixels of the photos?  Because different cameras produce various shapes, and in the real world, unmodified photos typically do not fit either the print paper, or the monitor shape, until cropped.

Comment: Doesn't your TV offer a way of selecting "pillarbox" display of 4:3 images?

Comment: Check the menu/settings of your TV, there should be an 'exact' or 'dot-by-dot' mode. Sometimes it is hidden a few levels deep but you should be able to do so. Also, if it does it by default, you need to disable overscan to avoid photos being cropped too.